# How to access an Authentication on Siam Commercial Bank Developer API

Tags: curl, postman

Currently I'm learning to use Siam Commercial Bank (SCB) developers. but I encountered to obtain an access token. I'm using Postman to test it. Based on their [Authentication](https://developer.scb/#/documents/documentation/basics/authentication.html) doc. there are 3 ways to obtain access token.

1. when testing the 'Client Credentials Grant Type,'  I received an error message
   [image]

here is my cURL

```
curl --location 'https://api-sandbox.partners.scb/partners/sandbox/v1/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'resourceOwnerId: <api key>' \
--header 'requestUId: scb_64d954221b6302.12594372' \
--header 'accept-language: EN' \
--data '{
    "applicationKey" : <api key>,
    "applicationSecret" : <api secret>
}'
```

2. I attempted the 'Authorization Code Grant Type' test and successfully completed step 2: Request Authorization, managing to receive the response
   [image]
   I'm currently confused about what I should do next based on this response. Therefore, I attempted to use the cURL command from the 'callbackUrl' link.

here is my cURL

```
curl --location 'https://api-sandbox.partners.scb/login/06f33e33-fcc1-401a-816e-26dfd36e9fe6' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'requestUId: scb_64d956fb68d8f5.29899265' \
--header 'resourceOwnerId: <api key>'
```

and I got this error response
[image]

3. I attempted to test token generation from the dashboard
   [image]

I tried generating both token types for 2-Legged OAuth and 3-Legged OAuth, but neither token was usable.

Please advise me on how to proceed with Authentication / Authorization.